# What should I play over this rhythmic slash notation?

Tags: piano, chords, jazz

(I'll work on getting a better picture)

I'm playing as the pianist for a jazz ensemble and Ive encountered a specified rhythm in slash notation, however there are no specified chords.

This is a replication but it looks something like this (this is repeated once more)

[image]

Normally, I would play the specified chords over the slashes however in this particular example there are no chords specified like in other parts of the song, and the last chord notated (a G7) does not seem to work over what the rest of the ensemble is playing. What would be the most appropriate thing to play here?

If it helps, the song is Arnge Drank by Paul  Baker

Comment: This is where ears come in useful. Listen to what is needed, and play appropriately. We can't always have reference to the charts, and sometimes have to use those most useful appendages.

Comment: Are there any chords on the chart at all? If so, the last written chord would be played here. If not, I think it would have to be by ear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image comes from m. 193. Looking at the conductor's score, the chords (given above the guitar staff) are `Ab7(sus4)` and `Bb(sus4)`. When the notation repeats in m. 195, the chords are `C7(sus4)` and `D7(sus4)`.

[image: "Arnge Drank" mm. 193–196]
(Image Source: [YouTube](https://youtu.be/My1ou2pZTsU?t=303))

Comment: Ah okay, that isn't written in on my part

Comment: Looks to me like the chords were only written above one part in the score and then not copied into each part. For anybody that wants to know: you can use the Inspector in Sibelius to show chord symbols in parts but not the score. Finale and other notation programs presumably do the same.